# ISNULL expression shows ??? -s in the result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, isnull

I have a query which is similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    Field.Table1, 
    Field.Table2, 
    ISNULL(Field.Table3, 'My text here') 
FROM Table.
```

'My text here' is in Georgian Unicode (which literally looks like this 'ვერცხლი'). As a result of my query I get ??????? -s instead of the text I've put in ISNULL. The same happens when i try to input Russian Cyrillic as 'My text here' .

`Field.Table3` is `nvarchar(150)`, not null. It can get `NULL` in my query because of the `Outer Join` I use there (which I did not mention above).

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: That's a character set issue. Somewhere in your code->db->client->display rendering chain, you're using a differnt charset, causing your DB contents to get corrupted. The rendering chaing has to use the SAME charset throughout, or be connected with appropriate conversion logic.

Comment: If SQL Server you are missing the `N` prefix. `ISNULL(Field.Table3, N'ვერცხლი')`

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Martin, many thanks it worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use N before string definition

```
SELECT 
    Field.Table1, 
    Field.Table2, 
    ISNULL(Field.Table3, N'My text here') 
FROM Table.
```